# I'm unable to retrieve state.Check this code and my output

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have declared a state in class Header.But I can't retrieve that state using {this.state.characters}.Kindly help me to solve.

```
class Header extends React.Component{
    state={
        characters: [
            {
                'name': 'sakthi'
            }
        ]
    };
    render(){
        var style1={
            color:'#9876[enter image description here][1]56'
        }
    return(
        <div>
            <h1>Hello World !!</h1>
            <h4 style={style1}>{this.state.characters}</h4>
        </div>
    );
}
}
```

"sakthi" should be printed on my screen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this.state.characters` is an array of objects and it's impossible for React to know how to print, or which property to print. So instead you should use map function to loop thru the array and define how you want it to be

```js
return(
  <div>
    <h1>Hello World !!</h1>
    {
      this.state.characters
        .map(x => (<h4 style={style1}>{x.name}</h4>))
    }
  </div>
);
```

Comment: @sakthikumaran: No problem, just remember to mark it as answer for reference in case anyone else facing the similar issue. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should represent the array of objects (`this.state.characters`) like an array of JSX to render it:

```js
class Header extends React.Component {
  state = {
    characters: [
      {
        'name': 'sakthi'
      }
    ]
  };

  renderCharacters = () => this.state.characters.map((c, i) => (
    <h4 key={i}>{c.name}</h4>
  ));

  render(){
    return(
      <div>
        <h1>Hello World!!</h1>
        {this.renderCharacters()}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```